# Emacs indentation doesn't work when looking at the same file with VIM

Tags: vim, emacs, indentation

I'm having a problem with indentation in Emacs.

Whenever I'm indenting code in Emacs it looks fine, but when I look at the same code in VIM/Github/Eclipse, there's parts of code that isn't indented.

Examples:

This is what I see in Emacs:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

This is what I see in the other editors:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

The languages I'm seeing this in is:
- C
- Java
- JavaScript

I haven't tried to simulate the behaviour in other languages atm...

I'm also seeing these symptoms in some of the code I receive from some of my teachers that I know use Emacs to generate pre-code that I'll be looking at in Eclipse/VIM/Github.

One extra thing: using 'cat' on linux displays indentation, made by Emacs, correct! It's the only thing besides Emacs that can do that....

Is there any way to prevent this? It isn't a big problem, but VERY irritating atm and I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very likely a tabs vs. spaces issue.  Emacs is probably displaying the tabs as eight spaces as this is the standard that cat would use.

Run `:set list` in vim to see what characters are making up the whitespace.  If you want the indentation show up the same you either need to configure all the editors to use the same indentation (preferable) or configure them to at least show tabs as the same number of spaces.

Relevant vim settings: `expandtab`, `tabstop`.
Relevant emacs settings: `tab-width`, `indent-tabs-mode`.

Comment: Similarly, `M-x whitespace-mode` should indicate the whitespace characters for you in Emacs. There is a lot of information on the Emacs Wiki about configuring indentation, as well as many other Q&As here at S.O. All in all it's probably more complex that you'll expect, so you might want to anticipate spending some time reading up on the details.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now with indent-tabs-mode disabled. Also great tips regarding :set list and M-x whitespace-mode to see the changes.